# Coldfusion <cfreturn>, returns nothing

Tags: function, coldfusion

I have a simple cffunction that calls a webservice and returns a token.
It's been working for quite sometime, but recently it's returning nothing.

```
<cffunction name="getICEToken" access="public" output="no" returntype="string" returnformat="plain" description="Sets token for access to ICE webservices">
    <cfargument name="username" type="string" required="yes" />
    <cfargument name="password" type="string" required="yes" />
    <cfargument name="memberID" type="string" required="yes" />
    <cfargument name="partnerID" type="string" required="no" default="#this.partnerID#">

    <!--- initialize local var to hold method-specific vars --->
    <cfset var local=structnew()>
    <cftry>
    <cfscript>
                    local.postTo='/membership/Member.asmx';
                    local.soapAction = 'someURL';
                    local.method = 'AuthenticateUserByMemberId2';
                    local.myAccessToken = '';
            </cfscript>
            <!--- generate soap request content to get our access token --->
    <cfsavecontent variable="soapBody">
    <cfoutput>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <#local.method# xmlns="#local.soapAction#">
          <WsUserName>#xmlformat(arguments.username)#</WsUserName>
          <WsPassword>#xmlformat(arguments.password)#</WsPassword>
          <PartnerId>#xmlformat(arguments.partnerID)#</PartnerId>
          <MemberId>#xmlformat(arguments.memberID)#</MemberId>
        </#local.method#>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
    </cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>


            <!--- send webservice request to ICE --->
            <cfhttp url="https://#this.host##local.postTo#" method="post" result="local.httpResponse">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPAction" value="#local.soapAction##local.method#" />
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="accept-encoding" value="deflate;q=0">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="te" value="deflate;q=0">
        <!--- pass in the xml-formatted request --->
        <cfhttpparam type="xml" value="#trim(soapBody)#" />
    </cfhttp>


    <!--- if the status code is 200, we have a successful response --->
    <cfscript>
            if(find( "200", local.httpResponse.statusCode )) {
            // Parse the XML --->
            local.soapResponse = xmlParse( local.httpResponse.fileContent );
            // Pull the specific nodes we need from the XML --->
            local.responseNodes = xmlSearch(local.soapResponse, "//*[ local-name() = '#local.method#Result' ]");
                            // set to struct
                            local.strResult=ConvertXMLToStruct(local.responseNodes[1]);
                            // writeoutput('converted token response to structure<BR>');
            // dump the response data --->
                            if(local.strResult.success) {
                                    local.myAccessToken = local.strResult.UserAccountToken;
                                    // writeoutput('access token acquired: #local.myAccessToken#<BR>');
                            } else {
                                    // writeoutput('access token NOT acquired<BR>');
                                    // stopanddump(arguments,0);
                                    // stopanddump(local.strResult);
                            }
                            // set token to THIS scope
            this.ICEtoken=local.myAccessToken;

                    }
            </cfscript>

<!---
If I uncomment this:

<cfdump var="#local.myAccessToken">
<cfabort>

the dump shows the 172 character token

But, when trying to return this value, the calling function shows [empty string]

--->


            <!--- return token --->
            <cfreturn local.myAccessToken>


    <cfcatch type="any"><cfdump var="#cfcatch#"><cfabort></cfcatch>
    </cftry>
    </cffunction>
```

If I hardcode a value such as

```
<cfreturn 'some 172 character string'>
```

this will successfuly return the value.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: can you post an example of your code?

Comment: Does your actual code have an equal sign inside the cfreturn tag?

Comment: What is the indication that your function is not returning anything?

Comment: You have "if the status code is 200, build and return a token" but no else block.  Try writing one that returns the status code.

Answer (score 3):

Your `cfreturn` is invalid

```
<cfreturn myToken = webservice.struct.token>
```

If you want to return `webservice.struct.token` Your `cfreturn` should just be

```
<cfreturn webservice.struct.token>
```

Comment: yeah that was an error on my part.  I didn't cut and paste my code. I just typed it in.  I'll fix it.  But, yeah I didn't do that in my code.

Comment: copy and pasting your actual code would help us notice any errors. Writing pseudo code that doesn't re-create the issue isn't going to help us debug.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's not my code. It's the API pulling back a null value. The token I was outputting to begin with was a dummy account to initialize the CFC. I wasn't outputting the correct api call.